# i get black image with rotating code in python

Tags: python, image, matrix, rotation

```
 i write this code and all i get is black image when i run it it doesnt rotate. i imported the                 functions i will use first. then i defined which image i want to rotate with the degree as well.
```

so i assumed that the images are equal on rotation and original. when i apply the matrix of rotation i cant get the result i expected . i get a black image instead of the rotated.

this is my first task as well where i have to skew it at the same time as well but i am going to do that after i get the rotated result if any idea to help me in this task i would really be grateful for that .

```
# define the image input and rotating degree
I = cv.imread('test.jpg')
degree1= 45
RAD1=math.radians(degree1)

# get the dimensions #
height = I.shape[0]`your text`
width = I.shape[1]

# we assume the rotated image is equal in size with original. #
I_rotated = np.zeros(I.shape)
rotated_height = I_rotated.shape[0]
rotated_width = I_rotated.shape[1]

# get the mid rotating points . #
mheight = height // 2 
mwidth = width // 2

#  for each pixel in output image, find which pixel #
#it corresponds to in the input image #
for c in range(rotated_height):
for f in range (rotated_width):
x = ((c-mheight)*math.cos(RAD1))+((f-mwidth)*math.sin(RAD1))
y = (-(c-mheight)*math.sin(RAD1))+((f-mwidth)*math.cos(RAD1))

#add the offest we got to match the original image in points.#

x += mheight
y += mwidth 
 # round the points 
x = round(x)
y = round(y)
 #check if x/y are corresponds to a valid pixel #
if (x>=0 and y>=0 and x<I.shape[0] and  y<I.shape[1]):
rotated_I[c,f,:] = I[x,y,:]

 # print the images

cv.imshow('rotate',I_rotated)
cv.waitKey(0)`
```

Answer (score 0):

With OpenCV you will almost never need to loop through each pixel. OpenCV is designed to abstract away that tedium. In this case, use `getRotationMatrix2D()` and `warpAffine()`.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import math

# define the image input and rotating degree
image = cv.imread('test.jpg')
degree = 45

# get the dimensions
height = image.shape[0]
width = image.shape[1]

rot_matrix = cv.getRotationMatrix2D((width/2,height/2), degree, 1) 
rotated = cv.warpAffine(image, rot_matrix, (width, height)) 

cv.imshow('rotate', rotated)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: i cant use these functions . i need to build it from scratch . any idea how